# How to conditionally extend express request defenition, depending on using middlewares

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

E.g. i have two middlewares and two controllers.

```
router.get('/path1', middleware1, controller1);
router.get('/path2', middleware2, controller2);
```

When I include middleware1, I extend req type with someProps1 (using declare namespace Express). But typescript allows use req.someProps1 in controller2, and it is the problem, because in fact req.someProps1 doesn't exist in that chain.

Is there way to extend request object only for certain middleware chain?